# xcode sliding drawer using masonry autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, drawer, masonry-ios-osx

I'm having issues on creating an sliding drawer for a phone app, so, I have a landing screen and I have to display a drawer with animation, I already have the content of the drawer using masonry autolayout and I need to have the drawer animation and also the possibility to scroll up the drawer to close it, do you know how to handle that kind of animation using masonry autolayout?

Comment: Did the proposed solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Grab a hold of the `NSLayoutContraint`, and change it's `constant`.
This can also be animated.

Replacing a `NSLayoutContraint` programmatically will also have the same effect.